# Difficulty Understanding Solution to Marginal and Joint Density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, marginal-distribution

[image]

[image]

I was able to solve part (a) using spherical coordinates. Part (b) is a completely different story. I'm not sure how the bounds were derived from the corresponding integral. Would someone on MSE be kind enough to explain to me where the bounds come from each of the corresponding integrals? For example, I get the z-bounds but why was z solved for from the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ rather than $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$? Honestly, I'm very confused by this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we get the marginal PDF by integrating the joint PDF over the other variables. So to get $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ we need to integrate $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)$ over $z.$ The support of $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = \frac{3}{4\pi}$ is the solid sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 < 1,$ so we need to integrate over all $z$ satisfying that bound. This is $$ -\sqrt{1-x^2+y^2} < z < \sqrt{1-x^2+y^2}.$$

Similarly, if we want $f_{Z}(z)$ we need to integrate over the region of the $x$-$y$ plane satisfying $x^2+y^2+z^2<1,$ i.e. over the sphere with radius $\sqrt{1-z^2}.$

Comment: @WhatsDUI  $f_{X,Y}(x,y) =0$ for $x^2+y^2>1$ (any point outside the circle is outside the sphere). So we only need to calculate for the points inside the circle. Similarly in the second part, $Z$'s support is $[-1,1].$ I'm not sure what needs elaboration for $f_Z(z).$ Can you expand?

Comment: Wait question, where does the 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1 come from? Are you essentially letting z = 0

Comment: For Z, are you just solving for (1-z^2) = 0, to find the bounds in which z is defined

Comment: @WhatsDUI No, I'm finding, for fixed $z\in[-1,1],$ the points in the x-y plane for which $x^2+y^2+z^2 < 1.$ This is the region you need to integrate $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)$ over to get $f_Z(z).$ (Or, rather, it's the region of the x-y plane for which $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\ne 0.$)

Comment: Why is z fixed between [-1,1]?

Comment: @WhatsDUI Cause we are calculating the marginal distribution of $Z$ at some point $z.$ We fix $z$ and integrate over $x$ and $y$. And $|z|>1$ is easy since that just has to be zero (it's outside the sphere).

Comment: Ahh thank you! Sorry, I'm really bad at probability so it didn't make much sense at first haha